# highlight a div linked to the current page

Tags: html, css

I'd like the buttons (moon, planets, etc...) staying red when we are on the current page.

Link to my site: http://www.chooseyourtelescope.com/moon-telescope/
Here, the "moon" button should be red.

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<a href=""><div class="top-logos"><img src="" alt="LUNE"></div></a>
<a href=""><div class="top-logos"><img src="" alt="PLANETES"></div></a>
<a href=""><div class="top-logos"><img src="" alt="CIEL PROFOND"></div></a>
<a href=""><div class="top-logos"><img src="" alt="SOLEIL"></div></a>
<a href=""><div class="top-logos"><img src="" alt="TELESCOPE POLYVALENT"></div></a>
```

**CSS**

```
.top-logos {
width:20%;
top:108px;
padding:5px;
position: relative;
text-align:center;
float: left;
background:#0e0e18
}

.top-logos:hover {
background:#dd0000;
}
.top-logos:active {
background:#dd0000;
}
```

I don't know anything about Javascript but I can use it if you tell me what to do. Also I've JQuery installed.

Comment: How is your page generated? When I click a menu item to go to a different page, the `.current-logo` class does not update. We need that to change when you click a menu item. If your website is all one page and is updated only via Javascript then we can change the class pretty easily with JQuery. If you website is served up by PHP, for instance, it is better to update the class in the static HTML or in PHP itself.

Comment: I'm not sure I ll answer your question but those buttons are not on a WP page editor but on a php file (base.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you already have this set up on your site with the `.current-logo` class on the anchor tags.

In your CSS file, all you need to do is

```
.current-logo div {
    background-color: #dd0000;
}
```

You need to make sure that the `.current-logo` class changes based on what page you are on.

It looks like you're using Wordpress so the best way to do it would be to use the built-in menu functionality. You need a register your menu in *functions.php* and it will automatically update based on the pages you have for your site. You can read about that [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus).

Per your comment about it being in a file called *base.php*, you could do something like this in *base.php*:

```
<a href=".../moon-telescope/" <?php if (is_page('moon-telescope')): echo 'class="current-logo"'; endif; ?> >
    <div></div>
</a>
<a href=".../planets/" <?php if (is_page('planets')): echo 'class="current-logo"'; endif; ?> >
    <div></div>
</a>
```

Change to match your pages.

Comment: After checking, your site doesn't change that class based on which item is clicked. Hold on while I update my answer.

Comment: @edou777 I updated my answer. Doing the built in menu functionality is the best way, but if you just want a quick solution that will work right now, you can simply edit *base.php*.

Comment: I chose the quick solution ;) But I ll see the other one when I ve more time. Ill need it for my side menu. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You already have the class `current-logo` on the appropriate element. Just style that:

```
.current-logo div.top-logos {
  background-color: #dd0000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I already tried that but it doesn't work.

Comment: You have to put that further in the file than the `.top-logos` style. They have the same 'weight', so whichever comes last overrules the other. If it still doesn't work, open the developer tools (F12), inspect the element and check which styles are overruling others.

Comment: And I was wrong. You should style the div inside the link. The div is what is getting the background color. You can set backgrounds on its parent too, but they won't be visible. See edit in the question.